# How to use props to change URL in iframe of react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, react-props, react-component

My webpage needs to display only the videos that correspond to the chosen subject matter. I need to pass the url in as a prop to the component, but I can't get it to work. If I hardcode the url then the iframe renders. If I try to pass the url as a prop I get a "YouTube refused to connect" error with a broken link symbol in the iframe. 
Here is my component. For a sanity check I checked to make sure that the url (called source in my code) would print to the screen, and it does.

```
function VideoItem(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>{props.item}</h3>
      <h4>Name: {props.name}</h4>
      <h4>Subject: {props.subject}</h4>
      <p>Description: {props.description}</p>
      <p>source: {props.source}</p>
      <iframe 
        title={props.name}
        width="560" 
        height="315" 
        src={props.source}
        frameborder="0" 
        allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" 
        allowfullscreen="">
      </iframe>
      <hr />
    </div>
  );
```

In my list of videos, the url is listed like this:

```
source: "https://youtu.be/restOfAddress"
```

I couldn't find any other questions where the url was passed in as a prop. There was one thread about urls on map APIs, but that didn't answer my question.
Thanks.

Comment: Is it just the `source` that is problematic, rest of the `props` are fine?

Comment: Yes. The rest of the props are fine. And I can also render the source url as text. This shows the url
<p>source: {props.source}</p>

Comment: What happens if you analyze the `iframe` with the browser inspector? Which is the value of `src` attribute?

Comment: @Emanuele - The value of src is correct. Interesting.

Comment: try to `console.log` the `prop.source` in every render and check which is the value of the `source` (little trick, you can do in that way `title={props.name || console.log(props.source)}`, it is an hack just to not modify the rest of the code)

Comment: Output from console.log: https://www.youtube.com/embed?v=ETSl8gWsFZ0. If I cut and paste that, I also get an error. However if I change it from embed to watch it works in my browser. Neither seem to work in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A source [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/forum/t/youtube-refused-to-connect/245262/3) suggests to set `embed` instead of watch:

`<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/rLMHGjoxJdQ"></iframe>`

See if that helps.

Comment: Thanks. Just tried that. It didn't change anything.

Comment: I had retrieved the URL of the video while it was playing in a playlist. I tried again with the URL of the video not in the playlist, and used embed, and the iframe appeared. So that is progress. Now, however, I get a different error message as soon as I hit play. "An error occurred. Please try again later. (Playback ID: fOlgvhJYua4ZR2wx) "

Comment: After a bit of playing around this was what worked. It wasn't just replacing watch with embed. I had to replace "watch?v=" with "embed/". It is an error I could have avoided if I had used the YouTube tool to get the embed code, instead of using the URL.

Comment: Oh yes, its the finer details sometimes. Glad it worked out!